# High Sierra installer has "sealed resources" v2 but says "resource envelope is obsolete"

Tags: macos, high-sierra, code-signing

Setting up a new laptop...

I downloaded the Install macOS High Sierra.app from the app store on an El Capitan machine.

"codesign --verify --deep" on the .app says:

```
/Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app: resource envelope is obsolete (custom omit rules)
```

However "codesign -dv /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app" says

```
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=177
```

Is this normal? From my reading I understood (probably wrong) that version=2 is the current rather than obsolete version?